# organize import into sbt file of netlib package

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use in Scala [org.netlib.util](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/f2j/javadoc/org/netlib/util/package-tree.html) package. How I can organize the LibraryDependencies in `build.sbt` file? I don't know the version of `org.netlib.util`...

My code need to be improved:

```
"org.netlib.util"%%"all"%"?"
```

Comment: I can't find the jar in maven repo? Did you have a jar locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this in your `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.f2j" % "arpack_combined_all" % "0.1"
```

The [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.f2j/arpack_combined_all/0.1) is where you want to look for how to include managed libraries in your `build.sbt`. They have a handy tab that gives you the exact code to use (clicking on the 'SBT' tab versus, say 'Gradle' or 'Maven'). Below, you can see the libraries included, which include `org.netlib.util`.

Perhaps of note, the Maven search bar is not particularly useful, especially if they don't host a given package. However, Googling 'org.netlib.util sbt repository' gives you this result quickly.